# Is it possible to deploy application from visual studio to Azure VM (windows 10)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure

I am trying to deploy an application in azure VM which has windows 10 OS (not widows server). I have installed web deploy 3.6 and see that web management service is also running in VM. But still i get below error

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

Could not connect to the remote computer ("vmwin10dns.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE. Unable to connect to the remote server

Answer (score 0):

Usually the Start Type of Web Management Service is Manual.

After downloading and installing Web Deploy, one has to go to `Programs and Features`, find `Microsoft Web Deploy`, and then `right-click and select Change`. Click `Next` on the first page, then Change on the `second page`, and one will come across this window:

[image]

Make sure that both IIS Manager UI Module (as well as everything beneath it) and Remote Agent Service are selected.

Once that is done, when one navigates to Server Manager and click on the IIS tab, one will see that both the Web Management Service and the Web Deployment Agent Service are now running automatically:

[image]

Try these and make sure all the services are up and running. It should work then.

Hope it helps.